# How do I pass an object to a form?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am working on a VBA script with Microsoft Word that allows the user to select text that will be be copied to the clipboard so that it can exported to an Excel file. The user will make a number of selections and finally indicate he/she is done when the contents of the clipboard will be copied to a template Excel file.

The form `frmModelessForInput` allows the user to select text which is copied to a string variable (`str_clipboard`), press the "Continue" button to repeat selecting other text and then press "Done" when the text string is copied to the clipboard and then pasted to the Excel file opened earlier.

The problem is that when I try to paste the contents of the Windows clipboard to the Excel file in the cmdDone sub of the frmModelessForInput form the wb_open object gives me an error 91 about half the time. I had the same problem, I believe, in the Check_Excel_RTM_Template_Test sub and solved it by passing the oExcel object to sub.  I am trying to pass the oExcel object to the form but it is presenting the same error as with the previous sub even though I incorporated the Property for the form as suggested below.

I have created the "minimal" code and have added comments to explain key tasks that each sub is accomplishing. I have run this code and it fails in the same manner as my "production" code.

Thanks in advance for helping me solve my problem.

Main Module

```
' This is the minimal master module where I open the Excel Template and Word document to process
Option Explicit
Public str_clipboard As String
Public i_how_many_sentences, i_starting_row_ID As Integer
Public str_active_document As String
Public str_Excel_Filename As String
Public b_abort As Boolean
Public i_rows_of_data As Integer


Sub Master_Module_Test()
Dim oExcel As Object
Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
str_Excel_Filename = "C:\Test\Excel_Template.xlsx"
str_active_document = "C\Test\Doc_to_process.docx"
Documents.Open (str_active_document)

oExcel.Visible = True
oExcel.ScreenUpdating = True 
oExcel.Workbooks.Open str_Excel_Filename
Call Check_Excel_RTM_Template(oExcel)
i_how_many_sentences = 0
Call Select_Sentence_Form_Test(oExcel)
End Sub
```

Sub in main module

```
   ' This sub now works without errors
    ' The calling routine passes the object oExcel....this approach works
    ' Previously I didn't pass oExcel but used the following statements
    ' Dim wb_open as Workbook
    ' Set Wb_open = ActiveWorkBook
    ' This also worked sometimes and failed about half the time

    ' This sub checks the Excel file whether it is of the expected format and then selects the cell where the new data will be pasted
    ' I have only included the statement to do the selection
    ' This sub works without any errors
    Sub Check_Excel_RTM_Template_Test(oExcel As Object)
        oExcel.ActiveSheet.range("A6").Select
    End Sub
```

Sub in main module

```
' This sub activates the frmModelessForInput so that the user can select sentences; the form executes and works as expected
Sub Select_Sentence_Form_Test(wb_open As Object)
    Dim frm As frmModelessForInput
    Set frm = New frmModelessForInput
' Here is where I set the property of the frmModelessForInput to open Excel workbook as suggested in the response 
    Set frmModelessForInput.Book = wb_open
    With frmModelessForInput
        .str_word_doc_filename = str_active_document
        .str_no_copied = "0"
        .Show False
    End With
    Set frm = Nothing
End Sub
```

function to extract the filename from the full pathname.

```
Function getName(pf)
getName = Split(Mid(pf, InStrRev(pf, "\") + 1), ".")(0) & ".xlsx"
End Function
```

frmModelessForInput form code

```
' Here I implemented the suggested property for the form 
' I changed the declaration to "Object" since oExcel in Master_Module_Test is declared as an object
Option Explicit
Private m_Book As Object

Public Property Get Book() As Object
   Set Book = m_Book
End Property

Public Property Set Book(ByRef Value As Object)
   Set m_Book = Value
End Property



' This sub works without errors
Private Sub cmdContinue_Click()
    Dim str_clipboard_line As String
    Dim i_row_number As Integer

    ' When the "Continue" button is pressed the code selects the sentence at the cursor and adds the contents to str_clipboard variable
    i_row_number = i_how_many_sentences + i_starting_row_ID
    i_how_many_sentences = i_how_many_sentences + 1
    Call Highlight_Sentence(str_clipboard_line, i_row_number)
    frmModelessForInput.str_no_copied = i_how_many_sentences
    str_clipboard = str_clipboard + str_clipboard_line
End Sub

Private Sub cmdDone_Click()
    Unload frmModelessForInput
 '  When the "Done" button is pressed the contents of the str_clipboard variable is copied to the Windows clipboard
    Dim str_filename As String
    str_filename = getName(str_Excel_Filename)
    MsgBox "I will now copy the data to the Excel file."
    Dim wb_open As Object
    Set wb_open = ActiveWorkbook
    Call SendToClipboard(str_clipboard) 'This sub puts the contents of str_clipboard into the Windows clipboard
    ' The following statement works sometimes but other times it has runtime error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set
    wb_open.ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
    MsgBox "Done pasting data to: " & getName(str_Excel_Filename)    
End Sub


' This sub works without errors
Private Sub Highlight_Sentence_Test(clipboard As String, i_row_no As Integer)
    Dim txt_sentence, txt_page_no As String 
    Dim txt_section_index As String
    With Selection
     ' Collapse current selection.
     .Collapse
     ' Expand selection to current sentence.
     .Expand Unit:=wdSentence
    End With
    txt_sentence = Selection.Text
    txt_page_no = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
'I Use tabs to line up data in the correct columns in template file
    clipboard = i_row_no & vbTab & str_active_document & vbTab & txt_page_no & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & txt_sentence & vbCrLf
End Sub
```

Comment: We need more information in order to test this. Can you supply a [mcve], please? Just the bare bones, plus any explanation required to set this up in both Word and Excel.

Comment: I updated the question with the complete "minimal" code.  See above.

Comment: Not having tested anything yet I notice a problem in `cmdDone_Click`: You refer to `ActiveWorkbook` but there's no reference to the Excel application. This can't run...? The code also uses a functoin `getName`, but that's not in the code you provide.

Comment: The function getName returns the filename from the string that contains the full path.  It's been working fine.  Being a VBA novice I thought that adding the code below to define the Property for the form would allow we to reference wb_open object which was defined in the calling routine as an Excel application.  Can you provide me code changes to fix the issue you address?  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by adding a new `Property` to your form.  In your form, add the following code:

```
Private m_Book As WorkBook

Public Property Get Book() As WorkBook
   Set Book = m_Book
End Property

Public Property Set Book(ByRef Value As WorkBook)
   Set m_Book = Value
End Property
```

Then in your calling code, add the Workbook you want to use, something like this:

```
Set frmModelessForInput.Book = wb_open
```

or:

```
Set frmModelessForInput.Book = ActiveWorkbook
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  But I must be missing something.  No matter what I tried `wb_open.ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial...` is nothing in the cmdDone code. The suggested properties code compiles without error.  What suggestions do you have to find where the object is being dropped?  The object wb_open is open in the calling routine just before I load the `frmModeLessForInput` form.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that the code in the question is not working with the correct Excel objects. Since everything to do with Excel is declared as data type `Object` VBA isn't able to provide more exact error messages - it's having to *guess* what is meant. It might help to set a reference to the Excel object library (Tools/References) and declare the exact data types until the code is working correctly. Then, if you want to use late-binding instead, the declarations can be changed to `Object`.

Here are some examples of how the incorrect object types are being passed around, which is causing VBA to get confused.

In the following procedure I've added an `Excel.Workbook` object declaration and instantiate it when the workbook is opened. Since the UserForm needs to work with a workbook object *this* is passed to `Select_Sentence_Form_Test`...

```
Sub Master_Module_Test()
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook 'Object
    Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
    str_Excel_Filename = "C:\Test\Excel_Template.xlsx"
    str_active_document = "C\Test\Doc_to_process.docx"
    Documents.Open (str_active_document)

    oExcel.Visible = True
    oExcel.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wb = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(str_Excel_Filename)
    Call Check_Excel_RTM_Template(oExcel)
    i_how_many_sentences = 0
    Call Select_Sentence_Form_Test(wb)
End Sub
```

In the question in the code the *Excel application* is being passed and is being assigned to the `Book` property. VBA is allowing it because everything is typed as `Object`. But when it comes time to *use* the workbook, it doesn't work (logically not).

```
Sub Select_Sentence_Form_Test(wb_open As Object) 'As Excel.Workbook
    Dim frm As frmModelessForInput
    Set frm = New frmModelessForInput
' Here is where I set the property of the frmModelessForInput to open Excel workbook as suggested in the response
    Set frmModelessForInput.Book = wb_open
    With frmModelessForInput
        .str_word_doc_filename = str_active_document
        .str_no_copied = "0"
        .Show False
    End With
    Set frm = Nothing
End Sub
```

Then `cmdDone_Click` does not work with the property *and* it tries to access `ActiveWorkbook` even though there's no `Excel.Application` object qualifier, nor available in this procedure. This is Word VBA, it doesn't "know" `ActiveWorkbook`.

Instead, the code should use the `Book` property (that's why it was created, after all).

```
Private Sub cmdDone_Click()
    Unload frmModelessForInput
 '  When the "Done" button is pressed the contents of the str_clipboard variable is copied to the Windows clipboard
    Dim str_filename As String
    str_filename = getName(str_Excel_Filename)
    MsgBox "I will now copy the data to the Excel file."
'''        Dim wb_open As Object
'''        Set wb_open = ActiveWorkbook 'can' work without Excel.Application
    Call SendToClipboard(str_clipboard) 'This sub puts the contents of str_clipboard into the Windows clipboard
    ' Uses the Book property 
    Me.Book.ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
    MsgBox "Done pasting data to: " & getName(str_Excel_Filename)
End Sub
```

Note that I haven't tested this since it would take too much time to set up the environment.

Comment: I have modified my VBA code with your suggestions.  It compiles fine.  However, when I run it I get a runtime error on `Me.Book.ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True` of 'Automation Error: The callee (server [not server application]) is not available and disappeared; all connections are invalid. The call may have executed.'  Any ideas of the fix?

Comment: I also tried changing the form property declaration from "object" to "workbook" as suggested by Brian Stafford and received exactly the same error.